# Select all elements except a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide `.menu_branch` using jQuery `slideUp()` only if the user clicks off of `.menu_root`. I'm not getting any errors but the `click()` function is executing even if `.menu_root` is clicked. Any ideas? jQuery or straight JavaScript are both fine by me. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<span class="menu_root">Menu</span>
<ul class="menu_branch">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu_branch {
    display:block;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$("body:not(.menu_root)").click(function(){
    $(".menu_branch").slideUp("fast");
});
```

I've also tried:

```
$("body").not(".menu_root").click(function(){
    $(".menu_branch").slideUp("fast");
});
```

As well as replacing `body` with `*` in both instances, all with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to prevent the propagation of click event from `menu_root`

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $(".menu_branch").slideUp("fast");
});
$('.menu_root').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3mL35/)

Your code will ignore a `body` element with class `menu_root` like `<body class="menu_root">`

Comment: One note for future viewers, this only works after the first click on the page. In order to fix that, I wrapped Arun's code inside a `$(document).ready()` function. So I ended up with `$(document).ready(function(){Arun's code here});` and it works perfectly.

Comment: As a user I'd prefer to be able to open the closed menu too (http://jsfiddle.net/3mL35/3/)

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Yes, much better. +1 for using slideToggle (because I didnt think of it)

Comment: I definitely agree. I'm actually using a site-wide slideUp/slideDown function and added this piece to complete that function. My supplied code is mimicking the menu in its open state. I didn't think of slideToggle either, I might play with that a bit. Thanks, both!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("body").click(function(event){
    if ( $(event.target).hasClass("menu_root") ) {
        return false; 
    }
    $(".menu_branch").slideUp("fast");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WzW2D/2/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately it didn't work for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party again but this should work for you. Clicking `.menu_root` will toggle the menu. Clicking anywhere else will close it (if its open).

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {//When the user click on any element:
    if($(".menu_branch").is(":visible")){//If the menu is open...
        $(".menu_branch").slideUp("fast");//close it.
    } else if ($(e.target).hasClass("menu_root")){//Otherwise, if the user clicked menu_root...
        $(".menu_branch").slideDown("fast");//open it.
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xGfTq/

Comment: I'm happy with the current answer because it plays well with my global slideUp/slideDown function that I'm using on this and other elements, but I appreciate your answer, late or not. There's some stuff in there that I didn't know and I'm sure I'll use it in the future, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $(".menu_branch").slideUp("fast");
});
$('.menu_root').click(function () {
   return false;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work for my purposes.